# How can I calculate the sum of eastern numbers in a 2D matrix?

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array

I need to solve various problems with the numbers in a 2D matrix, in areas divided by the diagonals (e.g. count the number of even numbers in the southern part of the matrix).

My problem is, I can't figure out how to select the eastern numbers. I should add that I want the eastern numbers excluding the ones on the diagonals themselves.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to know how to decide whether a cell is between the right of the two main diagonals (from top left to bottom right and from bottom left to top right) . I'll just provide a hint: Can you do it if you only want to check for cells to the right of the top-left-to-bottom-right diagonal? How about the other diagonal? How about combining them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is, I can't figure out how to select the eastern numbers ... excluding the ones on the diagonals themselves.

Break down your problem into two:

1. Separating the North-Eastern half (above the main diagonal) from the South-Western half (below the main diagonal).
2. Separating the South-Eastern half from the North-Western half (above and below the secondary diagonal).

Then just select those elements which are in the upper half according to the main diagonal, and the lower half according to the secondary one - a simple intersection.

Focusing on the first of the two problems - how about we think about the diagonal itself? The diagonal has the elements `m[0,0]`, `m[1,1]`, `m[2,2]` etc. - or in general, if `m[i,j]` is on the diagonal, then `i == j`. Now, any point above the diagonal is above some `m[i,i]` on the diagonal, so it's `m[i,j]` with `j < i`. Any point below, similarly, has `j > i`.

This should be enough for you to craft your full algorithm.